# JAVA how would I calculate the sum of each row in a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am writing some code to calculate the total of each row in the array.

```
    public static int sum(int[][] array) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < array[i].length; k++) {
            total = total + array[i][k];
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

The code above is to work out the total sum for all the numbers in the two dimensional array however I am trying to work out to the total for each individual row for the array.

```
    public static int[] rowSums(int[][] array) {
}
```

I am very unsure on what to do for the code to work out the 2D array for each row.

Comment: use an array to store the `total` of each column. That way you can `total[k] = total[k] +array[i]k];`

Comment: If any answer have helped you, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Did you mean something like this :

```
public static int[] sum(int[][] array) {

    //create an array of size array.length
    int[] result = new int[array.length];
    int total;

    //Loop over the first dimension 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        total = 0;//Make sure to re-initialize the total in each iteration

        //For each row calculate the sum and store it in total
        for (int k = 0; k < array[i].length; k++) {
            total += array[i][k];
        }

        //When you finish put the result of each row in result[i]
        result[i] = total;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example

```
System.out.println(
        Arrays.toString(sum(new int[][]{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}))
);
```

Outputs

```
[3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Like that you explained what was happening, for anyone looking for the answer in the future.

Comment: I used your code to post my answer (changing only **loops** by **enhanced loops**. I gave credit to you and also up voted your answer.

Comment: It's ok @zlakad feel free ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Java 8 you can do it in the following way:

```
int[] ar = Arrays.stream(new int[][]{{1,2},{3,5}}) // source
                 .mapToInt(arr -> IntStream.of(arr).sum()) // sum inner array
                 .toArray(); // back to int[]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar)); // print the array
```

Without stream:

```
int[][] arr = {{1,2},{3,5}};
// create a array that stores the total of each inner array
int[] total = new int[arr.length];
// first loop for outer array
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // loop for inner array
    for (int k = 0; k < arr[i].length; k++) {
        // since default value of total[i] is 0, we can directly use +=
        total[i] += arr[i][k];
    }
}
// print the array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(total));
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on @YFC_L answer, but using the enhanced loop:

```
public static int[] sum2(int[][] array) {

    //create an array of size based of how many rows the array has
    int[] result = new int[array.length];

    int rowIndex = 0;
    //Loop over each row
    for (int[] row : array) {
        int total = 0;

        //Calculate the sum of the row
        for (int n : row) {
            total += n;
        }

        //Store the sum in the result
        result[rowIndex++] = total;

    }
    return result;
}
```

Also, this method can be tested in the exatelly same way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
            Arrays.toString(sum2(new int[][]{{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}))
    );
}
```

and, of course the output is the same:

```
[3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with slight modification with your code

```
public static int[] sum(int[][] array) {
    List<Integer> rowTotal = new ArrayList<>();
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < array[i].length; k++) {
            total = total + array[i][k];
        }
        rowTotal.add(total);
        total = 0;
    }
    return rowTotal.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<Integer> sum(int[][] array) {
    List<Integer> total = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < array[i].length; k++) {
            sum = sum + array[i][k];
        }
        total.add(sum);
    }
    return total;
}
```

In case if you need to use int[] after getting result,

```
List<Integer> total = sum(ar); 
Integer[] result = total.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Use result object for further use.

Comment: Are you converting a `List` of `Integer` into a `String` array? [useful opinion-based gif](https://tenor.com/sedk.gif)

Comment: Updated my answer :)